# how can I call a function and pass params in a Python class?

Tags: python, class

I am attempting to use the Woo exchange trading api. They provided a snippet of code which is an impressive Python class structure. Copied below.

My question is how can I use it?

I have tried to run:

```
get_orders(self, 'BTCUSDT')
```

which throws an error "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

and

```
get_orders('BTCUSDT')
```

which throws "TypeError: get_orders() missing 1 required positional argument: 'symbol'"

Here is the code (class structure)  the kind woo guys provided:

```
import requests
import datetime
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
from collections import OrderedDict
#Application ID 9d4d96f6-3d3b-4430-966d-8733aa3dc3bc

#API Key
api_key = 'my_api_key'
#API Secret
api_secret = 'my_api_secret'

class Client():
    def __init__(self, api_key=None, api_secret=None):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret
        self.base_api = "https://api.woo.network/v1/"

    def get_signature(self, params, timestamp):
        query_string = '&'.join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in params.items()]) + f"|{timestamp}"
        signature = hmac.new(
            self.api_secret.encode('utf-8'),
            query_string.encode('utf-8'),
            hashlib.sha256
        ).hexdigest()
        return signature

    def get_orders(self, symbol):
        url = self.base_api + "orders/"
        params = {
            "symbol": 'BTCUSDT'
        }
        params = OrderedDict(sorted(params.items()))
        timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
        signature = self.get_signature(params, timestamp)
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'x-api-key': self.api_key,
            'x-api-signature': signature,
            'x-api-timestamp': timestamp,
            'cache-control': 'no-cache'
        }
        resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
```

So, to repeat and summarize, when I write my own code to use this class, how can I call the function get_orders() and, more generally, reference the elements in the class structure? Thanks, in advance, for help.

Comment: `c = Client(api_key, api_secret)` and then `c.get_orders('BTCUSD')`. That's a method of a class, not a function, you need to istantiate it if you want to use a method of a class.

Comment: Thanks, still something missing. {'success': True, 'meta': {'total': 0, 'records_per_page': 100, 'current_page': 1}, 'rows': []} There are some orders so it's baffling. I will check Woo out on their Telegram channel and then revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've truncated the code because *get_orders* doesn't appear to return anything.

However, you would start by constructing an instance of Client like this:

```
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
```

...then...

```
client.get_orders(None)
```

That may look a little strange but *get_orders* requires one parameter but it's never used. I don't think the implementation of *get_orders* is quite how it was intended to be because it will always use BTCUSDT

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. Almost there but not quite. 
I changed the prams, in the get order function, to
params = {
            "symbol": symbol
        }
which is what it was originally. I just hacked it to try and make it work.

and tried:
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
client.get_orders(None)
client.get_orders('BTC/USDT')
which did not produce an error, in either case, but returned no result. And there are orders for that pair, so I am puzzled. I will experiment some more, but if you have another idea that would be very helpful.

Comment: This is what I did
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
#r = client.get_orders(None)
resp = client.get_orders('BTCUSDT')
print(resp)
in the console I got None

Comment: As I said in my earlier comment, *get_orders* doesn't return anything explicitly. It's implicitly returning None. You probably need to add *return resp*

Comment: Thanks. I passed the wrong param. I should pass ''SPOT_BTC_USDT''. Grateful for your help, guys